# z-index not working on position absolute negative

Tags: html, css, z-index

Hi I'm making a progress bar with arrow as dividers, something like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        step 1
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        step 2
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        step 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.arrow{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/kGmg5/

But the arrows are always behind the `li` elements. Am I missing something? Is it possible to do this without changing the html?

Comment: remove the z-index on the li and it will work. Not sure why you need to push the arrows to the right, it should work without the -30, right: 0 should be fine. Then again maybe your setup is different than I think it is

Comment: The problem lies in your `right: -30px;` which is essentialls pushing the arrow to the right and behind the next LI which has a different stacking context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give an element a z-index, you create a stacking context for it. All other z-indexes on it's children will only take effect on that stacking context.

In your example, when you give your li's a z-index, you're creating a different stacking context for each of them. The arrows with the z-index will only be able to be able to get above other elements that belong to the same parent li's stacking context.

I hope I've made myself clear. But even if I did, checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context . It's got some good examples.

Without changing the html, you can, as Sunil Salunkhe suggested, remove the z-index on the li's. From what it appears, there's no reason for it to be there anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to The stacking context. That really helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Huangism is correct, the change that fixed the problem was the z-index on the li.

http://jsfiddle.net/kGmg5/9/

```
li{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    /* z-index:200;  Removed */
}
```

From his comment:

> The right -30 is pushing the arrows behind the next li and with the
>   z-index on the li, it creates a different stacking order

Comment: without the content it works as well, mainly due to the fact you removed the z-index on the li

Comment: You are correct.  You should answer this post to take credit, sir.

Comment: I am at work, you should just update your answer. The right -30 is pushing the arrows behind the next li and with the z-index on the li, it creates a different stacking order

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove z-index on `li`:

```
li
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```